# Prevent API client from leaking sensitive data

Tags: c#, api, security, communication

Suppose I have an API endpoint such as Facebook Graph API, which I design an application running on my PC to periodically connect to the API and retrieve my posts, comments, etc. On each Timer_Tick, the program reconnects to the API and brings the top 10 data items from the API, and persists these data into databases.

Now, suppose that this application is built by 3rd party, and I just downloaded from the internet as binary file not opensource.

How can I know if the application is leaking my Facebook data to third party without my knowledge?

Is there a mechanism to monitor such leaking if found? (from programmatic perspective)

Comment: You can reverse engineer it, but failing that it's a system of trust. Once you've given permissions to an application, either through giving them your login details (which you should never do) or through explicitly authorizing an application on your account, they have access to all of your data. If you don't trust an application simply don't give it access to your account, and be very cautious in that regard.

Comment: I am not worried about the data, I am more concerned with how to detect if there is leaking? programmatically, as I might need to run 50 applications as API clients now or 500

Comment: You don't really have any means of detecting it programmatically I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of security and for being sure you almost must think about any vulnerability here and try to make sure there is no way to reveal data by the known vulnerabilities but you cannot be sure about unknown ones. 
If this is  the matter of the trust and you are dealing with sensitive data i strongly recommend you to avoid using 3rd party tools unless they are provided or certified by the API provider. here are some techniques witch will help you understand about what is going on in the backyard but **they will definitely not guaranty the safety** :

1- First of all make sure the application is really a binary code (i know you mentioned it as a binary), it's because some executable files are just scripts or semi-scripts but look a like a binary files. for instance in the some cases if the source of the executable application is written with C#, Python, Java, there are tools out there that will help you DeComplie the application and find out what's going inside. this solution of course can be considerably tough if for example the code is obfuscated or there is complex models or OO programming models involved.

2- Use network monitoring tools like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or any other tool to capture all traffic of HTTP/HTTPS requests while using the 3rd party application. because the API is just the same as HTTP requests used by applications to exchange data you can use these tools to monitor what's going on in your computer. normally this application must only connect to the Facebook servers and URLs needed to use the web API, if there is any other request sent or received from a server other than the Facebook there is chance of data leak here. if these requests are not encrypted by `SSL/TLS` you would be able to see the data being exchanged or if they are encrypted through `SSL/TLS` there are tools that provide [man in the middle](http://viralzones.blogspot.ae/2013/08/man-in-middle-mitm-attack-using.html) attack solution to see these traffics but if they are encrypted in the application layer you won't be able to see what data are being transmitted so it might involve suspicion about data even higher chance of data leak. don't forget that this monitoring must be extended for the entire using cycle of the application.

Also limiting the application to talk only to the server in witch you are calling the API with OS Firewall will be step forward to decrease the chance of data leak here.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough reply, you gave me fat background on the subject.